# Can the spin lock deadlock when its interrupted from another CPU while locking between hardirq and softirq?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I was reading about how spin locks for hardirqs vs softirqs.

This is the docs:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-locking/hardirq-context.html

I understand that local interrupt is disabled to prevent hardirq(interrupt handler) from spinning forever and never letting the softirq a chance, from UP environment and maybe if both are stationed in the local CPU if SMP.

However, I do not understand what "secondly, the critical region could be entered by a hardware interrupt on another CPU" means.

Can a hardirq launched from a different CPU potentially deadlock? If so, how?

Comment: "Can a hardirq launched from a different CPU potentially deadlock?" - No, with proper locking it cannot deadlock. Proper locking is described in the docs you refer to: softirq calls `spin_lock_irq`, hardirq calls either `spin_lock` or `spin_lock_irq`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm specifically talking about how will a spin_lock_irq save me from hardirq launched from another CPU when all the code does is to disable local interrupt? also I believe the whole interrupt line for the handler is already disabled when entered, so everything is moot anyways? My question was what that sentence in the doc meant.

Comment: "I believe the whole interrupt line for the handler is already disabled when entered" - With `spin_lock_irq` you disable interrupts only on the **current CPU**. So interrupts could raise on other CPUs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hmm... I've read somewhere that interrupt lines get automatically masked out until interrupt handler finishes and reenables them on its way out.. So I was under the impression that interrupt handlers from same irq number shouldn't be able to run from other CPUs.

Comment: If two hard IRQ handlers running on different CPUs (perhaps executing the same IRQ routine, or perhaps executing different IRQ routines) use the same spin-lock, then they need to call `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore`. Otherwise, they only need to call `spin_lock` and `spin_unlock`.

Comment: Consult the [Cheat Sheet for Locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-locking/cheatsheet.html).

Comment: @IanAbbott My question is not about two IRQ handlers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am still unable to understand how a interrupt on another CPU could enter the critical region, when in fact it is being protected by busy wait?

Comment: "how a interrupt on another CPU could enter the critical region, when in fact it is being protected by busy wait?" - If a spinlock is used properly, then interrupt on another CPU can **raise** but cannot **enter critical region** which is executed on the current CPU.

Comment: I don't understand your question post and what kind of **answer** do you expect. The referenced document tells, that when you execute critical region on current CPU, you need to be prepared for interrupt on the current CPU, which could preempt your execution, and for interrupt on other CPU, which could enter into the same critical region. For protect your code from both "threats", you need to use proper locking, which is described in the doc.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I was reading the doc in a wrong context. Sorry for confusion. I got my oddities straightened out. Thanks!